# Second appender in log4net not working

Tags: c#, log4net

I have the following in my web.config:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="mainLog"
       type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="Log/Log.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%newline%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="linqLog"
      type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="Log/Log.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="MainLogger">
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="mainLog" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="LinqLogger">
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="linqLog" />
    </logger>
  </log4net>
```

The first appender called "mainLog" is working.  But the second one called "linqLog" is not.  If I comment out "mainLog", then "linqLog" works.

In my Global.asax file I have the following:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        }
```

Here is how I am calling them:

```
public static void LogMessage(string message, string loggerName)
        {
            ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(loggerName);
            log.Info(string.Format(message));
        }


LogMessage("My test message for MainLogger", "MainLogger");
LogMessage("My test message for LinqLogger", "LinqLogger");
```

Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Comment: I don't think log4net supports two appenders logging to same file, is there a reason why you are doing this?

Comment: Ah.. didn't know that.  I was doing this because I wanted the format of the messages to be different depending on source.

Comment: @LukeHutton You may want to actually create an answer to the question; that way I can award you the answer, since you were right. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two file appenders cannot log to the same file, unless you specify a `lockingModel`

`<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />`

See http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Log4net does support two appenders writing to the same file, but you need to set the locking model to "MinimalLock".

```
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
```